# Firebase messaging doesn't work after app reinstalls

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am running into a very weird problem. After uninstalling and reinstalling my iOS 11 app (coded in swift), I have to launch the app multiple times (10 to 20) before my firebase messaging works again. I change nothing in the code (sometimes I just wait and hour or so) and for some reason it seems that Firebase Messaging Notifications only work after relaunching my app multiple times. It's very important for my app to be able to receive notifications right when it's first opened as my app is basically reliant on them. I just need to find a way to get notifications to work when I first launch the app after I install it. I've attached images of my code. (I have method_swizzling enabled)

If someone could please help me I would really appreciate it. I've seen youtube videos doing the same things I'm doing and they're able to get messages to work right away. I've tried a lot of what I've seen online and other questions that seem to be like this but none of their methods seem to work. Thank you so much to anyone who tries to help!

[edit]

This is the code for the application launch function:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    application.statusBarStyle = ColorScheme.isDark ? .lightContent : .default
    FirebaseApp.configure()
//      Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
//      Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true
//      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in }
//      application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    setupMessaging(application: application)
}
```

This is the code for actually connecting and setting up my Firebase Messaging:

```
extension AppDelegate {
    func setupMessaging(application: UIApplication) {
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true
        print("channel established", Messaging.messaging().isDirectChannelEstablished)

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions, completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .sandbox)
        //TODO: Change for release
    }

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {

    }
}
```

And this is the debug functions that are called when I receive the notification:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    print("I got a notification")
    print(userInfo)
}

func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print("remote message received")
}
```

P.S. my AppDelegate extends MessagingDelegate and UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate

Comment: I uploaded the code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer! The problem was that I was using the online console firebase provides to send my test messages. I guess it time to register devices. I switched over to firebase functions to send my notification and then subscribed to a test topic with my phone and that fixed everything. I get notifications on first app launch now and I'm happy

Answer (score 0):

Please Check the below code

```
import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging



@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, MessagingDelegate {

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

    //REMOTE NOTIFICATION

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

    let token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken
    print("FCM token: \(token ?? "")")

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken as Data
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)
}

// This method will be called when app received push notifications in foreground
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
{
    completionHandler([UNNotificationPresentationOptions.alert,UNNotificationPresentationOptions.sound,UNNotificationPresentationOptions.badge])
}


// MARK:- Messaging Delegates
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID { (result, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error fetching remote instange ID: \(error)")
        } else if let result = result {
            print("Remote instance ID token: \(result.token)")
        }
    }
}


    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("received remote notification")
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this with method_swizzling enabled or disabled?

Comment: no. swizzling is not required
Check If you have your dev cert for APNS uploaded to Firebase console.

Comment: ok so I disabled method_swizzling. I uploaded the code but Swift is giving me an error when I try to do InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID { (result, error) in... It says that "Static member 'instanceID' cannot be used on instance of type 'InstanceID'". Any suggestions?

Comment: Add below to your code  ------ 

static func sharedDelegate() -> AppDelegate {
    return UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
}

Comment: Since you are trying to add to extension.. remove the extension for appdelegate and add the code to the claa appdelegate

Comment: I removed the extension from my AppDelegate but the `InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID { (result, error)` is still giving me an error. You can see it here [link](https://imgur.com/a/X54OOOs)

Comment: try removing the pod -- pod 'Firebase/Messaging' using pod update. Then Clean the Code abd again add pod -- pod 'Firebase/Messaging' and use pod update

Comment: That fixed the error but I'm still unable to get notifications when I first launch the app :(

Comment: 1. Check if you have enabled Push Notifications in your Project  Capabilities. 2. Are you using the correct dev certificate?

Comment: Yeah Push Notifications are enabled and I'm 99% sure I'm using the correct certificate since the notifications do work but they just take an hour or so after the app was downloaded to actually function correctly

Comment: Are you sending notification from Console or using any other backend?

Comment: I send them from the console

Comment: If they are coming means our code is fine. Can be issue from the APNS server side.